# Getting Junk data while uploading pdf file in AWS S3 through AWS lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Am trying to upload a pdf file in S3 through AWS lambda API gateway.
While logging the incoming file content it is getting logged as junk data. The same getting uploaded to S3 as well.

Am logging the incoming file like:

```
context.getLogger().log("Input File: "+apiGatewayProxyRequestEvent.getBody());
```

log printing like :

> Input File: ----------------------------332705484437312200761791
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"; filename="test.pdf"
> Content-Type: application/pdf
>
> %PDF-1.5 4 0 obj <</Type /Page/Parent 3 0 R/Contents 5 0 R/MediaBox [0
> 0 595.29998779 841.90002441]/Resources<</Font<</FAAAAH 7 0 R/FAAABB 11
> 0 R/FAAABG 16 0 R>>/XObject<</X1 9 0 R>>>>/Group
> <</Type/Group/S/Transparency/CS/DeviceRGB>>/Annots[13 0 R 14 0 R ]>>
> endobj 5 0 obj <</Length 18 0 R/Filter /FlateDecode>>stream
> x��[ks�H�+����7�~�jk��*�=�I��|� ۚ�
> q���z��!�8;����э�}�}�{����wO���s���F��H�"R<24����42�0B��L�B1<��zR����>D����t�q<������l�Rk�\�p�N

But normal text file files are getting uploaded properly. This problem occurs for pdf and docx files. Ho to upload the pdf and docx files in S3 through lambda API gateway

Comment: Have you setup [binary media types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html) for your API?

Comment: Is that pdf content ?

Comment: @Marcin yes i have added binary media types in api gate way setting

Comment: yes it is a PDF content @NghiaDo

Comment: so what the issue my friend?

Comment: i mean actual PDF content is converted to above junk values. each word converted ���l like this @NghiaDo

Comment: Both `docx` and `pdf` files are binary - you can't just log the text of it. The PDF log looks like it starts correctly but you'll have to download it and see if it's ok.